Mi app se rompe al colocar el cursor sobre elemento clickeable en KMP Desktop, error 'float androidx.compose.ui.util.MathHelperskt.fastCbrt(float)'
estoy programando en Kotlin Multiplatform para desktop, apenas en mis primeros pasos en esta tecnologia. Estoy utilizando la libreria Voyager para navegar, tengo 2 Screen y SI logro navegar entre las 2 Screen, para eso puse una caja en cada Screen y a cada una le asocie un evento 'clickeable' para navegar entre ellas, sin embargo me pasa frecuente que al colocar el cursor sobre el elemento clickeable la app se rompe, me envia una especie de Dialog de UI con el mensaje de error:
float androidx.compose.ui.util.MathHelperskt.fastCbrt(float)
No entiendo porque sucede, aca dejo la imagen del "Dialog" que me envia al romperse la app:

Porción del archivo MainScreen.kt:
Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(width)
                        .height(height)
                        .background(color = Color.DarkGray)
                        .constrainAs(box1) {
                            top.linkTo(parent.top, /*margin = 16.dp*/)
                            start.linkTo(parent.start, /*margin = 16.dp*/)
                            end.linkTo(box2.start, /*margin = 16.dp*/)
                            bottom.linkTo(box3.top, /*margin = 16.dp*/)
                        }.clickable { navigator.push(Box1()) },
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {

                    Text(text = "Usuarios", color = Color.White, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                }

Porción del archivo Box1.kt:
Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(width)
                        .height(height)
                        .background(color = Color.DarkGray)
                        .constrainAs(box1) {
                            top.linkTo(parent.top, /*margin = 16.dp*/)
                            start.linkTo(parent.start, /*margin = 16.dp*/)
                            end.linkTo(parent.end, /*margin = 16.dp*/)
                            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom, /*margin = 16.dp*/)
                        }.clickable { navigator.push(MainScreen()) },
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {

                    Text(text = "Usuarios", color = Color.White, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                }

Quiero que la navegación sea fluida, sin que la app se rompa.
